# ggplot2 plots the two variables in the same plot but one variable with reversed y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have one following example data:

```
df2 <- data.frame(supp=rep(c("VC", "OJ"), each=3),
              dose=rep(c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),2),
              len=c(6.8, 15, 33, 4.2, 10, 29.5))
```

Normally we plot the two variable `VC` and `OJ` in the same plot like this:

```
ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=dose, y=len, group=supp, colour=supp)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

What I would like to get is to plot `VC` in a reversed Y axis while still keeping the two variables in the same plot and share the same x axis. It should be like the pic below:

[image]

How can I do it with ggplot2? Thanks a lot.

Comment: So you want to reverse the values of `VC` but keep the y axis as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can multiply values of len for supp == VC by -1 and then plot as usual. 
Then, set new breaks and labels using `scale_y_continuous`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df2 %>%
  mutate(len = ifelse(supp == "VC", len*-1,len)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = dose, y = len, color = supp, group = supp))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-40,40), breaks = seq(-20,20, by = 20), 
                     labels = c(20,0,20))
```

[image]

Is it what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for.

ggplot2, does not handle the secondary axis very easily.  In order to reverse plot this variable, needed to multiple by -1 to reverse it.

```
library(tidyr)
#widen the dataframe, to separate the variables into different columns
df3<-pivot_wider(df2, id_cols = dose, names_from = supp, values_from = len)



ggplot(data=df3) +
  geom_line(aes(x=dose, y=OJ, group="OJ", color="OJ")) +
  geom_line(aes(x=dose, y=-1*VC, group="VC", color="VC"))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Dave2e, Thanks for your kind help. I did not state my question clearly. This is not what I want. I have added an expected picture in my question. Thanks again.